# How to update last modified user using windows auth info?

Tags: sql-server

I've a table `sales` containing sales records in SQL Server. I need a a column `modified_by` which shows the actor (user) of the last modification. Column `modified_by` should be filled by the user's ID related to the *Windows Authentication*.

```
         id      content  modified_by
-----------  -----------  -----------
          1          foo          Tom
          2          bar         Jack
```

If Tom updates Jack's record, then for the record 2, the column `modified_by` will show `Tom` instead.

This UPDATE action should be done automotically by the server for every record modification. Can it be possible ? Should I use trigger to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use TRIGGER to check rows after INSERT or UPDATE statement

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.after_update ON dbo.sales
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.sales
    SET modified_by = SYSTEM_USER
    FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.id = dbo.sales.id
```

[MSDN: CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table 
set lastmodifiedby =suser_sname()
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms174427.aspx)

you also can create a table with last modified as default ..

```
create table tt
(
id int,
lastmodifiedby varchar(100) default suser_sname()
)
```

Comment: Your answer do show the system user. However, I need something that can be executed automatically when someone do UPDATE operations. So that `modified_by` don't depend on user's decision

Comment: it doesnt depend on users decision,make the column as default

Comment: Are you saying,end users writes update queries and you dont want them to have control on changing ?..if so please update the question'

Comment: Of course, they can and they should have control, but I need to ensure the column `modified_by` is not forgetten by someone. In addition, they shouldn't have to be aware of this column all the time. SQL Server can handle the check alone

Comment: default does the same thing

Comment: DEFAULT does it for INSERT statement when `modified_by` column has not been specified, but not for UPDATE